# unordered_map with gregorian dates

Tags: c++, boost-date-time, boost-unordered

I would like to store `boost::gregorian::date` as key of a `boost::unordered_map` but I cannot compile the code as it is missing a proper hash function for this class.

1. An easy solution would be converting to `std::string` and store it. I possibly would like to avoid this solution as using string is quite expensive.
2. I tried to find some function exporting a date to number but I can read only the `day()` function and I am not sure if this is really suitable.
3. Maybe I can calculate the number of days between my date and a reference date?

Is there any other better way to store date or a function exporting date as number?

Comment: why not store it in a plain map?

Comment: For performance reason of course..map is a binary tree and unordered_map access is O(1)

Comment: you can get the julian day from a boost date, and there are plenty of ways to get a string representation. IS that what you are asking for?

Comment: .mm I was asking to converting it into a number instead of a string as using string is more expensive

Comment: thats why I mentioned julian day as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implement the hash function for it:

```
namespace boost { namespace gregorian {

inline size_t hash_value(date const& date)
{
    return boost::hash_value(date.julian_day());
}

} } // boost::gregorian
```

`julian_day` is simply the day index since Julian epoch start (whatever that is).

Comment: Is there a way to construct the boost::gregorian::date from juilian_day? I don't see it in the boost reference.