# How to store gregorian_date as a key of an unordered_map in c++?

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map

How to use unordered_map in which `gregorian_date` will be used as a *key* ?

```
unordered_map<boost::gregorian::date,int>date_map;
boost::gregorian::date sample_date{2018,01,01};    
date_map[sample_date]=1;
```

Can any one please help me.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::unordered_map<boost::gregorian::date, int>’ and ‘boost::gregorian::date’)

Comment: sorry brother that was my mistake. check the updated code. gives same error.

Comment: i think, you can use only date iterators

Comment: Be careful using the leading `0` for int literals in dates, it will cause errors for `08` and `09` since they aren't valid octal.

Comment: i tried with your instruction but sill gives error.

Comment: When I try it, the error is that there's no `std::hash<boost::gregorian::date>` implementation. This is a basic task with hash-based containers: either specialize it or pass a different class as the third template argument.

Comment: now how can i overcome this????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unordered\_map with gregorian dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084445/unordered-map-with-gregorian-dates)

Comment: @AnamulHasan I'd suggest you don't need quite so many question marks. If it's a genuine question, spend the energy typing the excess interpunction to search for "unordered_map std::hash implementation" instead?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is closely related to [unordered_map with gregorian dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084445/unordered-map-with-gregorian-dates), except you are using a `std::unordered_map` instead of the `boost::unordered_map`. You need to solve the same problem: If you want to use any data type as a key in an `unordered_map`, you need to provide a specialization of `std::hash` for that type (in your case `::boost::gregorian::date`).  Building on the answer given for the question I linked, you can use this specialization:

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace std {

// Note: This is pretty much the only time you are allowed to
// declare anything inside namespace std!
template <>
struct hash<boost::gregorian::date>
{
  size_t operator () (const boost::gregorian::date& date) const
  {
    return std::hash<decltype(date.julian_day())>()(date.julian_day());
  }
};

}

int main()
{
  std::unordered_map<boost::gregorian::date, int> date_map;
  boost::gregorian::date sample_date{2018, 1, 1};
  date_map[sample_date] = 1;
}
```

Comment: @Anamul If this answers your question, you can accept the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. If your problem is still not solved, maybe you can clarify your original question.